# Android device renders webview app diferent from Chrome Responsive inspect mode

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I have a Cordova app based on a Angular web page. The Android Cordova app does not render images like the Chrome responsive debug option. When I inspect the web page on 'Responsive' mode, it shows all layouts just like it is supposed to be, but when I build/install the app in a Android device, it does not render the CSS layouts like in the web page and the images and some part of elements's layouts gets way out of scale.

I have been using the CrossWalk https://crosswalk-project.org/ to help in this issue but I must remove the CrossWalk dependency from now on, and I would like to know how to fix this issue without having CrossWalk plugin installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never expect, that you can easily migrate from web to mobile version, mobile apps have their specific. And you can also get different results on android and ios devices, and for example android 6.0.0 and 7.0.0 may also give you different results. By analogy with cross browser support, you should do the same for different mobile platforms and versions. For example, old android versions do not support flexbox without specific prefixes - the latest do. Be ready, that you will need to spend a lot of time for convertation the web version to mobile app.

Comment: I see. Thank you.